# select image from name and index

Tags: java, android, image, android-layout

I would like to dynamically set the icon in the menu. The icons are named week01,week02.. and so on. Is there a way to change the icon by just use “week”+numer?

I had something like this in mind:

```
MenuItem item = mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_week);
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("week" + number, "drawable", "res.drawable-xhdpi");
item.setIcon(id);
```

This is how i do it now:

```
switch (number){
        case "01":
           item.setIcon(R.drawable.week01);
           break;
        case "02":
           item.setIcon(R.drawable.week02);
           break;
        case "03":
           item.setIcon(R.drawable.week03);
           break;
```

Comment: the first method is correct. The third parameter is wrong. You should use `getPackageName()` instead of `"res.drawable-xhdpi"`

Comment: Thanks it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments this is how it should be:

```
MenuItem item = mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_week);
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("week" + number, "drawable", getPackageName());
item.setIcon(id);
```